# How to delete a git branch created by git push origin?

Tags: git

I just want to rename a remote git branch from ker to kernel.
Without knowing the correct procedure I just issued the following command to take a backup and created a new branch name ker-org. But I could n't delete this new ker-org branch.

```
git push origin ker:ker-org

 origin/HEAD -> origin/master
 origin/demo
 origin/ker
 origin/ker-org
```

I am not a git expert, but when I tried the following

```
git branch -d origin/ker-org
error: branch 'origin/ker-org' not found.
```

Now, what have I done?
how can I delete this new branch ker-org?
How to revert the artifacts if any?

Comment: I am sorry missed line breaks here, origin/HEAD -> origin/master     origin/demo     origin/ker         origin/ker-org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to delete a remote git branch you need to use the `:branchname` syntax.

```
git push origin :ker-org
```

Comment: Why would you not prefer `--delete`?